# Combine numerical and boolean indexing

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(index=[0, 1, 2], columns=["test1", "test2"])
df.at[1, "test1"] = 3
df.at[2, "test2"] = 5

print(df)

    test1   test2
0   NaN     NaN
1   3       NaN
2   NaN     5
```

I tried the following line in order to set all NaN values at indices 1 and 2 to `False`:

```
df.loc[[1, 2] & pd.isna(df)] = False
```

However, this gives me an error.
My expected output would be:

```
    test1   test2
0   NaN     NaN
1   3       False
2   False   5
```

Comment: You want to use `df.loc[[1,2]].fillna(False)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
In [917]: df.loc[1:2] = df.loc[1:2].fillna(False)

In [918]: df
Out[918]: 
   test1  test2
0    NaN    NaN
1      3  False
2  False      5
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

`pd.isna(df)`is a mask the shape of your DataFrame and you can't use that as a slice in a `.loc` call. In this case you want to selectively update the null values of your DataFrame on specific rows, so we can use `.fillna` with `update` to assing the changes back.

```
df.update(df.loc[[1, 2]].fillna(False))
print(df)

   test1  test2
0    NaN    NaN
1      3  False
2  False      5
```

Comment: Interesting way to update as well, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Let us try with `fillna` and pass a `dict`

```
df = df.T.fillna(dict.fromkeys(df.index[1:],False),axis=0).T
   test1  test2
0    NaN    NaN
1      3  False
2  False      5
```